# Visual Studio 2010 Express will build a solution, but suddenly won't debug it

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, namespaces, reference

I have a solution that comprises two projects. The needed references are in place, and IntelliSense reflects this. I can build the project (F6).

However, when I try to debug it (F5), it suddenly tells me a namespace is missing (by suddenly, I mean it used to work fine). The namespace is there and I can F12 jump to classes in it.

I have an exception class in the "missing" namespace, but I use it in my code. It is not underlined (i.e. the IDE detects no error), but does underline the namespace reference. Doesn't make sense. The underline only occurs after I hit F5. Hitting F6 will remove it.

**EDIT**

I am unable to add any new namespace to the 2nd referenced project. By this I mean I can add whatever I want and build the project, but not debug it.

I can debug if I only keep the existing namespaces.

Comment: Check your references, do you have a reference to the output of the project, ie. a "reference to itself"?

Comment: I didn't change the references (i.e. from when it was working to when it wasn't). I checked through all the refs, and it doesn't reference itself.

Comment: Intellisense offers me the "missing" namespace. It's there.

Comment: Is the namespace in the other project? Do you have a reference to that project, or to the output of the project? I would try removing that reference and re-adding a reference to the project and see if that helped.

Comment: The namespace is in the other project. I have a reference to it. Intellisence is picking up everything in the other project no problem. But if I go to the a class in the namespace in question and view all references of it, it doesn't list the one I am having a problem with. But... how can if F6 build ok if there is a problem?

Comment: I removed the 2nd project and re-added it (plus reference). It didn't help.

Comment: Renaming the "missing" namespace in project 2 does result in it being renamed in the solution (main project), but it remains "not found".

Comment: Check if the project is built. Pull down the Debug/Release dropdown control in your toolbar and check the settings there. Make sure the rightmost checkbox is checked for both projects.

Comment: I deleted the output bin. F6 does rebuild the solution. I have VS Express... I don't see a Debug/Release dropdown. I went to another solution that uses the project in question, and I have the same problem there.

Comment: It seems something is corrupt on this 2nd project. How can I overcome this... can't just randomly delete files :-)

Comment: Can you post exact error messages? Also, importantly what type are these projects? Finally, can you be really clear about whether you are "adding namespaces" and when you are "adding references" - I'm finding it hard to follow what you are doing when you are adding a namespace (is this just adding a code file?)

Comment: I finally solved it by removing the project, renaming it in Explorer, creating a new project (with the original name), and simply adding each item from the old project. Hit F5 and it worked. The project had somehow corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me when referencing a dll that is using the .NET Framework 4 from a project that is using the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile. Visual Studios acts really weird and all IntelliSense works but it won't debug. I'm not sure if this is the same issue but it sounds a lot like it.

Comment: Well, it happened when I referenced an external ODBC library, so anything is possible. The ext library was targeted for an earlier version on the framework. Clearly a bug. However, when I re-created the problematic project, it worked fine. So a corruption, it seems.